# Почему padding блока не обрезает дочерний текст?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Почему padding блока не обрезает дочерний текст ?
[image: Картинка]

Comment: Паддинг - это отступ, а не рамка. У него вообще нет физического воплощения, чтобы перекрыть текст, это просто расстояние.

Comment: @Etki ,Хорошо.Почему тогда нету нижнего расстояния ?

Comment: Потому что вы сами указали height, который не позволяет сделать нижний отступ из-за того, что размеры вложенного контейнера больше внешнего. Потому что padding участвует в формировании координатов контейнеров, а не перекрывает их. Поэтому текст просто смещен.

Comment: @Etki вот решение http://jsfiddle.net/6g61ewdL/2/

Answer (score 1):

пиксели `padding`-а, добавляются к размеру блока т.е. `height:79px;`+`padding:20px` = `height: 119px;`

чтобы обрезало так как вам нужно, используйте внешний отступ `margin`

Comment: вот решение http://jsfiddle.net/6g61ewdL/2/

Comment: именно так, либо ширина, либо высота)